# Will overclocking my chipset increase the performance of integrated graphics?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, performance, cpu, motherboard

My AMD Radeon HD 5830 recently broke (overheated because the fan stopped working), and I am currently attempting to run games on integrated graphics, on my chipset.

Many games are responding slowly, including Team Fortress 2 at low graphics settings.
To my surprise, the only game that does not behave in this way is Crysis Wars (and quite possibly Crysis 1, too).
Of cause, the graphics performance is terrible (12.5fps at best), but I was still surprised that my integrated graphics chipset can actually run a Crysis game at this amount of FPS.

I do not have the money at the moment to purchase a new graphics card (XFX are refusing to RMA my broken graphics card, claiming it was my fault the fan broke when it was not [the card is still within warranty]), and this question has been in my head for a few days now.

My BIOS offers an option to overclock the Nvidia chipset.
*If I overclocked my motherboard's chipset, will I experience a significant improvement in graphics?*
This question doesn't have to be aimed at improving performance in games necessarily; it'd be quite nice to receive a significant graphical boost 'across the board'.

My motherboard is the Asrock N68C-GS FX, and have a AMD FX4100 CPU with 4GB DDR3 1066MHZ RAM.

Comment: It may be a good idea for you to keep a trusty backup GPU. I've had to pull out my old 6850 more than a few times and its really saved my buns.

Comment: @Ramhound This is a Nvidia 7025 chipset, motherboard's from 2009.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, NO. Overclocking your chipset will not get you a *significant improvement* in graphics while playing games. It probably won't even get you a noticeable improvement in graphics. You might get an extra 1-2 fps if you lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Just overclocking won't help that much, maybe 1-2% as An Dorfer already mentioned in the other answer.

But if your RAM is currently a single RAM module adding a 2nd one (same size & speed) will allow the motherboard to use the RAM in double-channel mode which nearly doubles RAM bandwidth.
Added benefit is that more RAM means less swapping which also improves performance for the entire system.
As a result FPS can get significantly better: 25-30% is not unusable in some games.

Extra RAM is usually cheaper than a new video-card. Your choice what you value more.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated graphics, loves memory speed.

Your DDR3 1066 is comparatively slow. Your processor supports DDR3 1866.

Pick up 8GB of Gskill Aries 1866 with 9 or 8 timing for $60 at Newegg. It should improve integrated graphics drastically. Won't make it better than a discreet card, but playable.

You could use the leftover memory for a HTPC or something like that.

Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#Modules) for more information about DDR3 speeds.

Comment: Stop the presses, upon further review, GeForce 7045 is just a 6150 with a few extra instructions. Not worth it at all, get better benchmarks, but still lousy FPM better, but still not great. Add another $60 and by a newer video card. Even if you don't have the extra $60, a $70 video card would be a good investment on that system.

Comment: What does a Nvidia product havr to do with the author's question?

Comment: On the author's system Asrock N68C-GS FX, 
the integrated graphics is on the motherboard a Nvidia GeForce 7025 chip.

Hope that clears up the confusion,

Kirsten: thanks for the clarifying edit, I didn't take the time to even organize my thoughts on that one